# rest api openam add user parametrised

Tags: bash, rest, openam

hello I have this script in bash:
first part : authentication against server - works fine.
second part: adds user - and this works fine when I define user directly in curl code - but when I want to add user from parameters.. then I got a message error:

> "{"code":400,"reason":"Bad Request","message":"The request could not
>   be processed because the provided content is not valid
>   JSON","detail":"Unexpected character ('$' (code 36)): expected a valid
>   value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at
>   [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@3a248e6a;
>   line: 2, column: 18]"}"

Any ideas how can I pass values to this script ? :)
Regards

```
#!/bin/bash

adm_user="admin"
adm_pass="secret"

user_name=""
user_pass=""

auth_url="http://url/OpenAM-11.0.0/json/authenticate"
add_user_url="http://url/OpenAM-11.0.0/json/users/?_action=create"

session_id=$(curl  \
      --request POST --header "X-OpenAM-Username: $adm_user " \
      --header "X-OpenAM-Password: $adm_pass" \
      --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
      --data "{}" $auth_url | cut -d"\"" -f4 )

sleep 1

curl \
 --request POST \
 --header "iplanetDirectoryPro: $session_id" \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --data \
 '{
    "username": "$1",
    "userpassword": "secret12",
    "mail": "bjensen@example.com"
  }' \
   $add_user_url
```

OK, mates I got the answer:

```
 '{
    "username": "'"$1"'",
    "userpassword": "'"$2"'" ,
    "mail": "bjensen@example.com"
  }' \
```